# Is there any way to execute Testng Script ( .java file) from console?

Tags: selenium, testng

I have prepared Testng - java formatted execution script. And now i want to execute it from command prompt using any batch file.Is this possible through cmd prompt. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp "<path-to-your-class-files>" org.testng.TestNG <path-to-xml>
```